# VSC - Git: Prompt to stash or rebase before checkout

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am pretty sure that before, when I had changes in a branch and I checkout to another branch, VSC will prompt me if i want to stash or rebase the changes.
Now it doesn't do it.

Kinda how GitHub Desktop does it [image]

How to get it back?

I checked every settings and reset them, didn't changed a thing

Comment: If the fact that I've seen it before was due to mistakenly taking VSC for GitHub Desktop, I filed [this feature request to VSC](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/177660)

Comment: Just FYI, this message is quite misleading: "You have changes on this branch." Actually, you have changes that are **not** on this branch, or on any branch yet. If you are able to switch branches without touching those files, then Git will let you and those pending changes will follow you around from branch to branch. If switching branches would touch those files (which would possibly blow away your unsaved work), Git will error. This is why you only *sometimes* get the error when switching branches with pending changes.

Comment: @TTT: while the error message is inaccurate and misleading it matches how **many** users (especially new ones) think about it. I suspect the Github Desktop team knows this very well and built this feature to remove friction for those user.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I'll buy that as a possible reason for it. Maybe there's room for improvement then; I feel like there should be a way to make the text both clear and accurate. This particular misunderstanding seems to cause a lot of confusion for new users later on, and it's possibly being made worse by affirming that assumption.

Comment: @TTT: I agree with that, but I guess it's the difference of "trying to offer the best Github Desktop experience" and "trying to make users fluent in git". Github Desktop focuses on ease of use, so I guess they picked their battle. On the other hand: if *a lot* of new users have the same common misconception about how some piece of software ought to work, then maybe that piece of software *is* wrong after all ;-) Insert "Principle Skinner Out of Touch" meme here.

Comment: I do agree with the message being misleading. Even though they want to be noob-friendly, it's a bad thing to learn misleading terms to noobs